# Signature for C function that returns a multidimensional array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, syntax

If I have:

```
char* buffer[8][8];
```

And inside the same file I want to write a function that returns this buffer, what would the signature of that function look like?

In the case of

```
char* buffer[8];
```

I could write

```
char** get_buff() {
    return buffer;
}
```

But in this case I cannot deference into a multidimensional array. The C compiler will tell me that

```
char* buffer[8][8]
```

has type

```
char * (*)[8]
```

The problem is that the type it gives isn't valid syntax in a signature, so I have no idea what it expects to go there. What should the signature look like?

Comment: if it's about C why do you tag C++?

Comment: I'm working in both. This syntax works in both C and C++

Comment: One cannot **return** **arrays** in C. It is only possible to return a pointer to an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a typedef. This compiles:

```
typedef char* (*tp)[8];
char* buffer[8][8];
tp get_buff()
{
    return buffer;
}

int main()
{
}
```

The type of tp is pointer to array of 8 pointer to char. So this returns a pointer to the first element of buffer. Each element of buffer has type array of 8 pointer to char.

Note that the type of buffer is actually array of 8 arrays of 8 pointer to char. But due to array to pointer decay, it decays to a pointer to the first element which is the type of tp.

Comment: Bad idea to hide a pointer behind a typedef. I would strongly recommend `typedef char* tp[8];` ... `tp* get_buff (void)` instead.

Comment: @Lundin I have never understood why hiding a pointer behind a typedef is such a horrible idea while hiding an array or an array of pointers or a function returning a pointer to an array or anything else are all perfectly OK.

Comment: Array typedefs and pointer typedefs both have similar readability issues

Answer (score 1):

Because of a limitation in the C language, you cannot return arrays from functions. You can only return pointers to arrays.

It will be easiest to work with *a pointer to the first element*. The first element in your case is of type `char*`, so a pointer to that would be `char**`. Please note that the pointer-to-pointer syntax has nothing to do with arrays as such.

```
// my recommended solution
char** get_buff (void) 
{
  return &buffer[0][0];
}
```

---

Should you wish to return a pointer to the whole array, it turns much more complicated. Advanced topic follows.

The array pointer to an array of type `char* buffer[8][8];` is declared as `char* (*ptr)[8][8]`. This is a pointer to the whole array. It would also be possible to use a pointer only to the first element, a `char* (*)[8]`.

If you wish to return an array pointer, the C syntax for it is truly horrible:

```
char* (*get_buff(void))[8][8]
{
  return &buffer;  // return address of array
}
```

This is completely unreadable. What we should do to avoid such C madness syntax, is to use a typedef to the array type, then return a pointer to such a type:

```
typedef char* c_arr_8x8 [8][8];

c_arr_8x8* get_buff (void)
{
  return &buffer;
}
```

---

Alternatively, it is perfectly fine to return the pointer through a parameter, although then we'd have to pass *the array pointer by pointer*:

```
void get_buff (char* (**buf)[8][8])
{
  *buf = &buffer;
}
```

---

Comment: `(char* (**buf)[8][8])` are you sure of this one ? `(char (**buf)[8][8])` seem more logic... or not I will never use this ;).

Comment: @Stargateur No, the element type of the array is `char*`. As for why the OP is using `char*` instead of `char`, I don't know. 2D array of pointer to strings?

Comment: The first element of a `char *[8][8]` has type `char *[8]`

Comment: As noted in my answer, the type of the first element is array of 8 char*, not char*. M.M is correct.

Comment: Not sure what you are all on about. The items of the 2D array is of type `char*` (array of array of char*). `char (**buf)[8][8]` would have meant that they were of type `char`.

Answer (score 0):

A function cannot return an array. In most cases expressions of array type are automatically converted to the pointer of the first element of the array, which is probably exactly what you want (unless you want to return a *copy* of the buffer, which is a whole different story).

So the return statement in your function should look like this:

```
 return buffer;
```

The type `char * (*)[8]` is correct and you absolutely can write a signature with it. It is not too obvious at first but nothing horribly complicated, really:

```
 char *(*get_buff())[8] {
     return buffer;
 }
```

A rule of thumb is: if a type has a single top level `(*)` in it, you stick your function name and parameters right after the `*` to get a signature. Like this:

```
      char * ( *   )[8]
                 ^
                 |
             get_buffer()
```

Same thing for multilevel pointers: the function name goes after the last `*` in `(*****....***)`.

Of course you can use typedefs to simplify the matter a bit.